# How to use rustup to install/use a specific history version of the component like: rustfmt, clippy

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How to use `rustup` to install/use a specific history version of the component like: `rustfmt`, `clippy`?

My intention is that i would like to lint my code base always on a specific version of the components like `rustfmt`, `clippy`, then only upgrade the versions after i purposely did the evaluation, instead of randomly moving to the latest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When installed through `rustup`, the version of `rustfmt`, `cargo`, `clippy` and other components is tied to the version of Rust you are currently using, not the latest version.

For example, on my system I get different versions of `clippy` if I specify `+stable` (1.56.1) or `+nightly` (1.58.0-nightly):

```
$ cargo +stable clippy --version
clippy 0.1.56 (59eed8a 2021-11-01)

$ cargo +nightly clippy --version
clippy 0.1.58 (d914f17 2021-11-16)
```

When using `rustup`, you can pin your project to use a specific Rust version (as well as corresponding versions for other components) by using a [`rust-toolchain.toml`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file) file, like this:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "1.56.1"
```